# Program that compares a read in string to a group of random letters will not find matches until at least seven letters

Tags: c, pointers

I am currently working on a project and due to the recent lockdown's am unable to meet with my instructors for help so I have come to you. My program is supposed to check to see what words from a randomly generated group of letters can be created by checking the supplied Linux dictionaries. Unfortunately, the program does not seem to produce matches until it begins searching for 7 letters or more and then crashes saying "realloc: invalid next size 0x0000000002473270". I have tried using valgrind but I have not be taught it yet so all the info it gives is extremely overwhelming. Here is the code, I know it has something to do with my pointers but please help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char dicNames[6][31] = {"american-english","cracklib-small","words@","british-english","README.select-wordlist","words.pre-dictionaries-common@"};

int main(int argCount,char *userIn[]){
    int i,j,k=0,l,numLetters,runTimes,count3Switch;
    char lSwitch[] = "-l";
    char tSwitch[] = "-t";
    char dicfilename[46] = "/usr/share/dict/";
    char **matchWords;
    char *nextWord;
    char *userLetters;
    FILE *dicFile;
    FILE *outputFile;

    if(argCount > 4){printf("Error. Too many inputs.\n\n"); return 1;}//checks if the user inputted too many arguments
    if(argCount > 1){//checks if user inputted a valid dictionary name
        for(j=1;j<argCount;j++){
            for(i = 0;i<5;++i){
                if(strcmp(dicNames[i],userIn[j]) == 0) break;
                if(j == (argCount-1) && i == 4){printf("Error. Invalid Dictionary.\n\n"); return 1;}
            }
            if(strcmp(dicNames[i],userIn[j]) == 0) {strcat(dicfilename,userIn[j]); break;}
        }
    }
    if(argCount > 2){//checks if the optional third argument is valid
        for(j=1;j<argCount;j++){
            sscanf(userIn[j],"%*c%*c%d",&numLetters);
            sscanf(userIn[j],"%*c%*c%d",&runTimes);
                if(memcmp((char *)userIn[j],(char *)lSwitch,2) == 0 && numLetters <= 99 && numLetters >= 1){count3Switch = 1; j = 5; break;}
                if(memcmp((char *)userIn[j],(char *)tSwitch,2) == 0 && runTimes <= 999 && runTimes >= 1){count3Switch = 2; j = 5; break;}
            if(j == (argCount - 1)) {printf("Error. Invalid Input for 3rd Argument\n\n"); return 1;}
        }
    }
    if(argCount > 3){//checks if the optional fourth argument is valid
        for(j=1;j<argCount;j++){
            for(i=1;i<argCount;i++){
                sscanf(userIn[j],"%*c%*c%d",&numLetters);
                sscanf(userIn[i],"%*c%*c%d",&runTimes);
                if(memcmp((char *)userIn[j],(char *)lSwitch,2) == 0 && numLetters <= 99 && numLetters >= 1) 
                    if(memcmp((char *)userIn[i],(char *)tSwitch,2) == 0 && runTimes <= 999 && runTimes >= 1){
                        j = 5;
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
        if(j == (argCount - 1)) {printf("Error. Invalid Input for 4th Argument\n\n"); return 1;}    
    }

/******************************************************************************************************/
//The above is solely command line argument validation. 
//It returns the number of runtimes as runTimes and letters as numLetters and the place of the dictionary as dicNum

    dicFile = fopen(dicfilename,"r");
    if(dicFile == NULL){fprintf(stderr,"Failed to open dictionary file\n"); return 1;}
    else{fprintf(stderr,"\nDictionary file opened successfully\n");}

/******************************************************************************************************/
//The above opens the dictionary and so now the program is ready to actually run
//57 lines of code and not a single thing has been done yet lol.

    if(argCount < 3){//provides the runTimes and numLetters is user does not specify
        runTimes = rand() % 1000;
        numLetters = rand() % 100;
    }
    if(argCount == 3){//generates whatever of the two inputs the user did not provide
        if(count3Switch == 1) runTimes = rand() % 1000;
        if(count3Switch == 2) numLetters = rand() % 100;
    }

/******************************************************************************************************/
//The above handles randomization in case the user does not specify runtimes and number of letters

    for(i=1;i<=runTimes;k=0,i++){
        for(j=0,userLetters = malloc(numLetters*sizeof(char));j<numLetters;j++){//randomly generates the users letters
            userLetters[j] = (rand() % 26) + 65;//makes the users letter all uppercase
        }
        printf("\nRun #%d\nUser Letters are %s\n\n",i,userLetters);

        matchWords = (char **)calloc(10,sizeof(char *));//allocation for the starting values of the 2-D array to store found words
        matchWords[k] = (char *)calloc(numLetters+1,sizeof(char));

        for(j=1;j<=numLetters;j++){
            printf("Words that are Size of %d:\n\n",j);

            while(feof(dicFile) == 0){
                nextWord = (char *)calloc(numLetters+1,sizeof(char));//allocates the space for the next word being read in from the dictionary
                fgets(nextWord,sizeof(nextWord),dicFile);//gets the next word from the dictionary

                for(l=0;l<strlen(nextWord);l++){//adjusts all letters to capital from dicationary
                    if(nextWord[l]>90) nextWord[l] -= 32;
                }

                if(strlen(nextWord) == j){//a limiter applied to search for words based on size of words first.
                    if(strspn(nextWord,userLetters) == strlen(nextWord)){//checks if the word on this line of the dictionary can be made from the user's letters
                        fprintf(stdout,"%s\n",nextWord);
                        strcpy(matchWords[k],nextWord);//copies the valid word to the 2-D of matched values
                        k++;
                        matchWords = (char **) realloc(matchWords,sizeof(matchWords)+sizeof(char *));//memory reallocation for next word address
                        matchWords[k] = (char *) calloc(numLetters+1,sizeof(char));//memory allocation for new word added to array.
                    }
                }
                free(nextWord);//frees next word so that it can be recycled for the next line of dictionary
            }
            rewind(dicFile);//resets the dictionary back to it's start
        }
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

```
==31588== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==31588== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==31588== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==31588== Command: ./a.out american-english -l8 -t5
==31588==

Dictionary file opened successfully

Run #1
==31588== Invalid read of size 1
==31588==    at 0x4E82943: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1661)
==31588==    by 0x4E8B3D8: printf (printf.c:33)
==31588==    by 0x401211: main (in /users/ctroche/ECE2220/Project5/a.out)
==31588==  Address 0x52002c8 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==31588==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linu        x.so)
==31588==    by 0x4011AB: main (in /users/ctroche/ECE2220/Project5/a.out)
==31588==
User Letters are NWLRBBMQ

Words that are Size of 1:

==31588== Invalid read of size 1
==31588==    at 0x4C32234: strspn (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linu        x.so)
==31588==    by 0x401332: main (in /users/ctroche/ECE2220/Project5/a.out)
==31588==  Address 0x52002c8 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==31588==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linu        x.so)
==31588==    by 0x4011AB: main (in /users/ctroche/ECE2220/Project5/a.out)
==31588==
Words that are Size of 2:

Words that are Size of 3:

Words that are Size of 4:

Words that are Size of 5:

Words that are Size of 6:

Words that are Size of 7:

Words that are Size of 8:


Run #2
User Letters are BHCDARZO

Words that are Size of 1:

Words that are Size of 2:

Words that are Size of 3:

Words that are Size of 4:

Words that are Size of 5:

Words that are Size of 6:

Words that are Size of 7:

BARABBA
BARBADO
==31588== Invalid write of size 8
==31588==    at 0x4013D4: main (in /users/ctroche/ECE2220/Project5/a.out)
==31588==  Address 0x67f3240 is 0 bytes after a block of size 16 alloc'd
==31588==    at 0x4C2CE8E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-lin        ux.so)
==31588==    by 0x4013A2: main (in /users/ctroche/ECE2220/Project5/a.out)
==31588==
BARBADO
==31588== Invalid read of size 8
==31588==    at 0x40137C: main (in /users/ctroche/ECE2220/Project5/a.out)
==31588==  Address 0x67f3240 is 0 bytes after a block of size 16 alloc'd
==31588==    at 0x4C2CE8E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-lin        ux.so)
==31588==    by 0x4013A2: main (in /users/ctroche/ECE2220/Project5/a.out)
==31588==
BARBARA
BARBARA
BARBARO
BARBARO
BOCCACC
BRADDOC
BRADDOC
CARDOZO
CARDOZO
CHARBRA
CHARBRA
COCHABA
CORDOBA

valgrind: m_mallocfree.c:304 (get_bszB_as_is): Assertion 'bszB_lo == bszB_hi' failed.
valgrind: Heap block lo/hi size mismatch: lo = 109301296, hi = 0.
This is probably caused by your program erroneously writing past the
end of a heap block and corrupting heap metadata.  If you fix any
invalid writes reported by Memcheck, this assertion failure will
probably go away.  Please try that before reporting this as a bug.


host stacktrace:
==31588==    at 0x3805DB16: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==31588==    by 0x3805DC24: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==31588==    by 0x3805DDA6: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==31588==    by 0x3806B092: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==31588==    by 0x3802CCA4: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==31588==    by 0x3802D007: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==31588==    by 0x380AEE81: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==31588==    by 0x380BDCBC: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)

sched status:
  running_tid=1

Thread 1: status = VgTs_Runnable
==31588==    at 0x4C2CC70: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linu        x.so)
==31588==    by 0x401291: main (in /users/ctroche/ECE2220/Project5/a.out)


Note: see also the FAQ in the source distribution.
It contains workarounds to several common problems.
In particular, if Valgrind aborted or crashed after
identifying problems in your program, there's a good chance
that fixing those problems will prevent Valgrind aborting or
crashing, especially if it happened in m_mallocfree.c.

If that doesn't help, please report this bug to: www.valgrind.org

In the bug report, send all the above text, the valgrind
version, and what OS and version you are using.  Thanks.
```

Comment: `sizeof(matchWords)` gives the size of the pointer and not the size of the allocated buffer. You need to store the buffer size in a structure yourself. Even if the `sizeof` did do what you wanted, why are you not increasing the size in the `realoc`?